# MPAndroidchart and stacked bar causes app to stuck

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have MPAndroidChart component in a layout. One of the bars is stacked while the others are not.

```
val.add(new BarEntry(1f,100));
val.add(new BarEntry(2f,new float[]{500,200});
```

I have 2 modes for the chart, one showing 2 bars (one stacked) and another one showing 5-10 bars (one stacked).

The first mode works but when moving to the 2nd mode, the chart stuck the whole app, sometimes before drawing and sometimes when trying to scroll the chart to show the rest of the bars (I set to show max 5 bars). There is no definitive rule for this. When removing the stacked one, everything works.

has anyone encounter such problem? Any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: I say this to most people when it comes to library issues, but consider making an issue on the their github as well to get feedback from the creators

Comment: I already posted this bug on Github but it seems that no on reads there. There are a lot of unanswered posts. The only way I could reach the developer was through a message in Facebook and the message never seemed to arrive to him. If you know a way to reach him, do share :)

Comment: no clue sadly, i just find posts to github to be more effective, so i recommend that to everyone, hope you find an answer :D